# How can Win XP be added to grub when Windows 7 is installed?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will Windows 7 pick up XP when grub is installed](https://superuser.com/questions/170823/will-windows-7-pick-up-xp-when-grub-is-installed)

I installed first Win XP (on the first partition), then Win 7 (second) and finally Ubuntu (third partition). To boot XP I now have to select the Win 7 entry in grub and then Win 7's boot entry for XP. How can XP be directly added to grub2's boot menu?

Comment: related: [How to install Windows XP when Vista and Win 7 are both installed on the computer already?](http://superuser.com/questions/67130/how-to-install-windows-xp-when-vista-and-win-7-are-both-installed-on-the-computer)